# Update if exists, else insert (without ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-update

I am trying to write a script to insert data from an API in a database, but if it already exists, update the data. Next to this, I want to delete data from the database if the data doesn't exist in the Array. (For now already happy if I could just have the update working)

Have been Googling for 2 days to find a solution for my problem, but nothing that I have tried has helped. For now I have the first time insert working, so it will write the initial call to the DB, but all next calls don't do anything. No updates or inserts anymore.

The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option is not possible in my case, because the id mentioned in my code is not the primary key of the table where I will be inserting in. (This code is just the example, the real database is a bit more complex and I can't change the tables itself).

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($content, true);
$sql = array(); 
$update = array(); 

foreach($array as $row) {

    // Create insert string
    $sql[] = '('.$row['userId'].', '.$row['id'].', "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['title']).'", "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['body']).'")';
    // Create update data
    $update[] = 'UPDATE TestDB.testTabel SET userId='.$row['userId'].', id='.$row['id'].', title= "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['title']).'", body = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['body']).'" WHERE id = '.$row['id']. ';';

    $flag = 0;
    $query = "SELECT id FROM TestDB.testTabel WHERE id =".$row['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
        $flag=1;
    }
    else {
        $flag=0;
    }
}

if($flag==1) {
    echo 'found!';
    mysqli_query($link, " ".implode('', $update));
    //print ''.implode('', $update);
}

else if ($flag==0) {
    echo 'not found!';
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO TestDB.testTabel (userId, id, title, body) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));
    //    print 'INSERT INTO TestDB.testTabel (userId, id, title, body) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql);
}
else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

I would want my script to check for every array line if it exists, if yes --> update, else --> insert.

So basically, what I want to do this (in pseudo code):

Get data from API

for each [API record] {
Query database to see if ID already exists

if (ID exists) {
update record
}

else if (ID not exists) (
insert record
}

else {
error
}
}

for each [DB record] {
check if DB id is in API data

if (DB id not in API data) {
Remove record from db
}

else {
do nothing
}
}

Really stuck now :( who could help me out?

Comment: `The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option is not possible in my case, because the id mentioned in my code is not the primary key` It doesn't need to, it can be a unique index. And since you want only one entry per ID it should have a unique index anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column that you want to use to check for duplicity does not have to be the primary key of the table.

From [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) :

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs

You should create a unique index on the column(s) where you want to prevent duplicates. Not only does it make possible the use of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, but also this is the correct way to represent your requirement in the database.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON mytable(column_1, column_2, ...);
```